# CAAnimation not working on SKView

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, caanimation

I'm trying to perform a "shiver" type animation on SKView (SpriteKit's UIView). The function is being called but the animation doesn't happen, as far as I can tell. I've tried messing with the parameters to make sure it's not simply doing the animation so fast it snaps back into place before I notice anything.

(Ideally I want to do this animation on a UITextField -- that's the commented out line.)

```
func shakeTheView() {

    println("huh")
    let anim = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform")

    let leftTranslation = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-10, 0, 0)
    let rightTranslation = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(10, 0, 0)


    anim.values = [ [ NSValue(CATransform3D:leftTranslation) ], [ NSValue(CATransform3D:rightTranslation) ] ] ;
    anim.autoreverses = true
    anim.repeatCount = 4.0
    anim.duration = 1.0

 //   self.globalPassphraseField.layer.addAnimation(anim, forKey: nil)
    self.view!.layer.addAnimation(anim, forKey:nil)

}
```

Comment: I don't think you can animate the SKView itself. Why not try it with the UITextField?

Comment: Trying it with the UITextField (globalPassphraseField) was the first thing I tried, no animation there.